# How do you do an equivalent scaling call in cocos2d as this Core Animation scale?

Tags: iphone, core-animation, cocos2d-iphone

I'm looking for something that does a similar call, but using cocos2d... the idea is to enlarge the sprite and then fade it out... Here's is a similar call in core animation:

```
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:ANIM_NORMAL];
someView.alpha = 0.0;
someView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale (3.0, 3.0);
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
id enlargeAndFade = [Sequence actions: [ScaleTo...], [FadeOut....], nil];

[sprite runAction:enlargeAndFade];
```

have a look here as well there will be plenty about so called 'actions': 
http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/forum/